# Global .scss file in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Is it possible to use a global .scss file outside of individual components? I did an "ng set defaults.styleExt scss" for using .scss in components but I can't really create a global .scss file in src or app. I'm using the new webpack/cli
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Just today README file for angular-cli was changed and included info about global style sheet. (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-styles)

Try adding styles.scss in either root folder or in app.

Comment: Have you tried this, yet? I can't seem to get it working. Neither in /src nor in /src/app

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The part about generating a new project works for the components using .scss but there is no global styles.scss file added. If I try to add one it doesn't work.

Comment: Documentations mentions to add it to apps[0].styles, can you try modifying your angular-cli.json so that it looks like:

apps: [{
  "main": "src/main.ts",
  "tsconfig": "src/tsconfig.jsoon",
  "mobile": false, 
  "styles": ["src/styles.scss"]
}]

Answer (score 1):

Your best option for now is to create a new `scss` file, and `@import` it in the beginning of your `*.scss` component. It's not perfect at all, but that way you can create a single source for variables and mixins (for now).

Comment: As of v1.0.0-beta.17 I'm not aware of a global `scss` file.